# How to reverse engineer Tibco ADB adapter code from BW5?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

We have old Tibco ADB adapter code that deployed to TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks 5.11.0 and using TIBCO ActiveMatrix Adapter for Database 7.0.0

For regular tibco packages  we can get source code from

```
\tra\domain\tibco\datafiles\
```

but ADB adapter code is not in the \tra\domain\tibco\datafiles\

Is it any way to get Tibco ADB adapter source code from tibco side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
In my case ADB adapter code ear has only configuration file inside which is why there were nothing for ADB adapter code in

```
\tra\domain\tibco\datafiles\<package_name>
```

configuration can be found in

```
\tra\domain\tibco\data\<package_name>
```

libraries and other included resources can be found in

```
\tra\domain\tibco\application\<package_name>
```